# asp.net mvc - RenderAction problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I'm not quite sure I understand what `Html.RenderAction()` does. I've just noticed one weird behavior when using it:

In `View/Contacts/Edit.aspx` I used `Html.RenderAction("ModalAddNote")` which contains form for adding Notes for Contact. This is for ajax usage (it is opened in modal dialog).
Problem occurs when I create method `ModalAddNote`: now, when I submit page for editing Contact I am being redirected to `Contacts/ModalAddNote` and not to `Contacts/Edit`. If I delete `Html.RenderAction("ModalAddNote")` then it works fine. Why is that so and how to control it?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Do you use BeginForm without arguments()? How do you show modal form? Do you avoid having form inside form? Do you remove modal notes form after it's submitted? Or do you submit contact without closing modal form?

Comment: I found the problem... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was... I had two `ModalAddNote` methods - one without and one with `HttpPost`, so when the page was submitted, `Html.RenderAction("ModalAddNote")` would call the one with `HttpPost` attribute